# Reading review posted data in mvc Web API

Tags: google-schemas

I know that question has been asked several times before but nobody answered.

My schema for review action in email is fine and posting perfect, but I cannot read the rating value and the reviewBody from posted data. I am trying to read them in MVC Web API.

Can anyone please help me how to read those values from the posted data?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I managed to resolve my self.
Here is what was my issue in case for someone who may have the same issue.

In my script (json+ld) i had 'review.ratingValue' for requiredProperty and it was validated fine but it was actually posting 'review.reviewRating.ratingValue'.